# How to avoid ::shdow from this style - "rock-where-used-grid::shadow pebble-accordion rock-grid::shadow iron-data-table::shadow #container iron-list"

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, shadow-dom

How we use mixins and how to avoid `::shadow` from the above style?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Custom properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-css-properties) and [mixins](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-css-mixins) are the way to go to avoid `::shadow`.